# Youtube api works with a bit of delay

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm using this script: https://github.com/iacchus/youtube-live-embed

Script works generally pretty well but when the streaming goes off it need about 3-4 minutes to find out that the stream is off. Even the video is showing that that stream is off, but `isLive()` is still returning `1`.

Is there any way to short that delay or get data from different functions?
Or this is typical for YouTube api to work that way?

Answer (score 0):

If the Google API returns that the live stream is still running, then there is no getting around that. Maybe you could increase the interval that you query the API.